# How do I check if an IP connection via ADB is successful using python?

Tags: python, adb

I need to sort through the IPs in the file, and those IP that successfully connected via ADB write in a separate file. I need help to verify that the connection is successful. I'm still new to this, here's what I managed to write:

```
import os

iplist = []

IPs = open("IPs.txt", "r")
valid = open("Valid.txt", "w")

os.system("adb tcpip 5555")

for test in IPs:
    iplist.append(test.split())
    ip = iplist[0][0]
    print(ip)
    os.system("adb connect "+ip+":5555")
    #check connection here
    valid.write(ip+'\n')

    iplist.pop()

IPs.close()
valid.close()
```

I only need to check that the connection is successful, everything else works. Which module can help me check if the connection success?

Comment: You can check what ` os.system("adb connect "+ip+":5555")` returns. If it returns 0, that usually means the code executed successfully. If not that means there was an error.          Also you can check out the subprocess module which provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results, according to the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Comment: os.system returns 0 ever if IP cannot be connected. About subprocess module - thank you, i will check if it works or not